# sed- unknown option to `s'

Tags: sed

I have this command :

> sed -i "s/plugins=(git)/plugins=(git zsh-autosuggestions
> zsh-syntax-highlighting zsh-completions)/g)" zshrc ;

Which give me a error :

> sed: -e expression #1, char 91: unknown option to `s'

I don't understand this error can someone explain ?

Thanks !

Comment: This parenthesis is voluntary, even without this the error still her. Ho my bad you right

Answer (score 2):

There's an extra parenthesis after `/g` in your sed command. Try this:

`sed -i "s/plugins=(git)/plugins=(git zsh-autosuggestions zsh-syntax-highlighting zsh-completions)/g" zshrc ;`